# vagrant & virtualbox: Two host only network interfaces are not allowed to overlap

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I need to set up a vm using vagrant I'd like it's attached to this existing Host-Only network adapter.

I've tried:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp", name: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
```

But it's telling me that another machine can't be attached to it.

Currently I'm getting:

> A host only network interface you're attempting to configure via DHCP already has a conflicting host only adapter with DHCP enabled. The DHCP on this adapter is incompatible with the DHCP settings. Two host only network interfaces are not allowed to overlap, and each host only network interface can have only one DHCP server. Please reconfigure your host only network or remove the virtual machine using the other host only network.

I need this vagrant virtual machine can see the other vm...

Several questions:

1. How could I change my `"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"` to `"vboxnet0"`?
2. Both vm has it's `Host-Only` ip address to: `10.0.2.15`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue too and searched to your question.
The lucky thing is that I finally got a solution.

This issue throwed by the *.rb file with a specific method there.
you just need to open the *.rb file and find the specific method and have a look of the source code.

There're three branch of a if-else statement. at the second branch code condition, you'll find a uppercase variable similarly here. Just search its definition and have look, it limited the IP range you should filled in the "VagrantFile". Just set an IP address within the limited IP range, this issue would be solved.

So sorry I haven't paste a picture here. My network is not well at my home, I just at company, and answering your questions now.